# kestrel use folder path in all urls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do set setup URL with subfolder to be localhost:5000/rootfolder/controller  i.e. localhost:5000/mysite/home

```
   var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want subfolder in URL path localhost:5000/site/controller instead of localhost:5000/controller

Comment: Remember that folders and url segments are separate concepts. I think you're asking for what we call a path base. You can get this with Map or UsePathBase.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your application available at `/site`, you can use the application path base to teach your application that it can run with that path base prefix as well.

Just call [`UsePathBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_UsePathBaseExtensions_UsePathBase_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString_) at the beginning of your Startup’s `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UsePathBase("/site");

    // …
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

By doing that, if you open your site at `/site`, everything will work as if you opened it without it, and generated links will also just include that path.